# How to create Windows Keyboard Shortcut Using Windows Logo Key

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

How would you create a custom shortcut key combination using the windows logo key?

For example, a non-declared windows combination like <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

For brevity; I'm looking for an answer that works, so if it requires things like altering registry keys I'm ok with that. I'm looking for an answer that *does not* use 3rd parties like AutoHotKey (<sub>although it wouldn't hurt to provide an answer using those for people that don't care and find it useful.</sub>)

I'm personally looking for a native solution or something I can change/add with default OS. Thanks

---

Wins 10 Home Edition

Comment: Win + C is _Open Cortana in listening mode_.

Comment: Oh neat. Thanks. I was just using that as an example

Comment: Probably settling on Win+1..9 is easiest - runs apps from taskbar without desktop shortcuts delay and background procs, for example you can add custom Python script shortcut on taskbar.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible without 3rd party programs.  Windows has reserved the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key for its own use and you need a program like AutoHotHey to intercept the keyboard press.

Windows will let you create custom shortcuts to files or folders in their `shortcut properties` dialog using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and a key of your choice.  However, the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> is not an option.